# Client for a local Java based service

Tags: c#, java, sockets, client, tcpclient

I am trying to connect my C# application with a local service that is based on Java. I dont have access to the Java code and the service details, the only thing I know is to communicate via socket through a specified port.

The problem is I can connect BUT cannot send / receive any data. My C# client code is as follows;

=====================

```
IPHostEntry ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress.AddressList[0].ToString()), 8888);
socket = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(ip);

Encoding ASCII = Encoding.ASCII;
Byte[] byteGetString = ASCII.GetBytes("Service_Command_Message");
Byte[] receivedBytes = new Byte[256];
string l_Response = string.Empty;

socket.Send(byteGetString, byteGetString.Length, SocketFlags.None);

//debugger gets lost at this line. I also tried stream.read    
Int32 bytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes, receivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
l_Response += ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, bytes);
while (bytes > 0)
{
    bytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes, receivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    l_Response = l_Response + ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, bytes);
}
socket.Close();
```

=====================

I tried using some port capture tool, that shows the connectivity but length of transmitted data is shown to be 0.

Thanks for any help.

======= update (using TcpClinet to send) ==========

```
client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8888);
stream = client.GetStream();

Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Service_Command_Message");

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

sw.WriteLine(p_Message);
sw.Flush();
```

========================================

I've used Flush() but still data is not transmitted till I close the application.

Comment: First of all, use SocketFlags enum values for readability on your send/receive methods. Second, can you get the errorcode from the out param of the send/receive, third anyway to verify if the bytes are being sent/received on the java side? (I'm assuming no to this one)

Comment: As far as read(..)/receive(..) is concerned, I cannot get its out param since the application / debugger hangs at this statement.
I cannot check what is receive at Java end, I don't have its code, its provided as an executable with some .jar(s) and .class(es). However, I have mentioned that the data transmitted is shown to be of 0 length on a local-loop sniffer tool.

Comment: The data transmitted is 0 as long as my C# application is RUNNING, when I close it, it "flushes' the data to the receiver and THEN the data is shown in the packet capture tool and the Java server's log.
How can I flush the socket buffer? or do I need to add a null / terminating character at the end of my message?
I've also tried using TcpClient, please have a look at the TcpClient code. It also has the same issue even after using Flush().

Answer (score 0):

Since your code hits the receive method, I'm assuming there isn't any problem with the send method. You should look at the out param of `SocketError` to validate this.

First of all, you cannot rely on the socket sending or receiving all the data. There is always a chance that you sent more bytes than what the client was expecting. Socket.Send method returns the amount of bytes sent, so you can use that to determine if you've sent all of the bytes:

```
Byte[] byteGetString = ASCII.GetBytes("Service_Command_Message");
int count = 0;
while (count < byteGetString.Length ) 
{
    count += socket.Send(
        bytes,
        count, 
        bytes.Length - count, 
        SocketFlags.None)
}
```

The reason why your receive method is hanging is probably because of your while loop condition:

```
while (bytes > 0) {
    bytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes, receivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    l_Response = l_Response + ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, bytes); }
```

You are assuming that when you receive zero length byte, you are done with the receiving but this may not be the case. You may have reached the end of your network stream when you fill some bytes on your buffer on the last loop. Therefore, you must change the while loop condition like so:

```
while (bytes == receivedBytes.Length) {
    bytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes, receivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    l_Response = l_Response + ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, bytes); }
```

If all this fails, there may be a distinct possibility that the Server isn't sending/receiving the bytes properly.

Finally, make sure to handle `SocketException` because the connection can be dropped at any time.

Comment: I noticed from the log of Java Server that my data is received AFTER I exit the hanged application. Does it mean auto-flush before exit? How can I do that myself?
Perhaps the unflushed 'Send' is preventing 'Receive'.